# Which statistical test should I use to compare two samples?

Tags: t-test, z-test

I have two groups and must conduct hypothesis testing by using an appropriate stats test. Seeing as I have 26 participants in each group, do not have the standard deviation (or any other information other than the data points for each group), I thought that the t-test would be the best choice.

null hypothesis = there is no significant difference between both groups
alt hypothesis = such a difference exists

Is there another statistical test that could be performed (like the z test or Fmax)? Is the t-test the only hypothesis testing that I should be doing here, or could I add another one?

Thank you

Comment: What hypothesis do you wish to test?

Comment: The null hypothesis is that there is no significant difference between both groups, and the alt hypothesis is that there is such a difference. Is this specific enough? Thank you @whuber

Comment: The word "significant" doesn't really belong in hypotheses, which are statements about populations. If you're interested in "no difference" vs "any kind of difference", that sounds more like a two-sample goodness of fit test. What are you actually trying to find out? What's the underlying question you're trying to address?

Comment: I'm afraid it is not sufficiently specific: you need to state *in what way* you want to measure any differences.  Are you concerned about differences of means? Medians? Variances? Distributions? Something else?  (Incidentally, a valid hypothesis can make no reference to "significance": that is a matter of how the hypothesis is *evaluated*.)

Comment: @Glen_b This is all for a research paper in which my study attempts to find out wether or not there's a significant difference between the failure rate of a sample of students who regularly watch Netflix and a sample of students who don't watch it at all. My data points represent the percentage of tests failed all throughout high school in both groups. I formed the hypothesis myself, and so the goal of this study. Could that be where the mistake is? How can I reformulate to make it work with a t-test? Thanks

Comment: Also, I calculated everything in function of a sample and not population (i.e. standard deviation)

Comment: Your responses are counts out of total counts, are they not (number failed/tests done)? This information is fairly important. Presumably also in a comparison of failure rates, a tendency to higher or lower rates matter much more than a difference in variability. Is that right, or does any kind of difference in distribution matter? Why do you want to "make it work with a t-test", rather than use a more suitable analysis?

Answer (score 2):

> My data points represent the percentage of tests failed all throughout high school in both groups.

This looks like count data; you'll likely have variance changing as the mean changes, skewness, and possibly distinct discreteness effects if the percentage of tests failed is small.

A more suitable approach than t-tests would be one suited to count data - chi-squares or perhaps binomial GLMs.

> This is all for a research paper in which my study attempts to find out wether or not there's a significant difference between the failure rate of a sample of students who regularly watch Netflix and a sample of students who don't watch it at all.
>   My data points represent the percentage of tests failed all throughout high school in both groups.

You might want to consider whether there are other important differences between the two groups.